# RNeo4j not installing in RStudio

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

Tried giving following command in RStudio 
devtools::install_github("nicolewhite/RNeo4j")

Got following error 
Installing github repo(s) nicolewhite/RNeo4j/master from hadley
Installing nicolewhite/RNeo4j.zip from https://github.com/hadley/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/archive/master.zip
Error: client error: (404) Not Found

Please advice what needs to be done to install the R Driver for Neo4J.

Comment: What version of devtools do you have?

Comment: apologies for late reply. I am using devtools version 1.1

Comment: Try updating devtools and try again.

Comment: devtools up to date, still failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122386/rneo4j-installation-hanging-not-completing).

This was it:

```
devtools::install_git("https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j")
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting following error <br> library(devtools)

* installing *source* package 'RNeo4j' ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object 'headers' is not exported by 'namespace:httr'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'RNeo4j'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/RNeo4j'
Error: Command failed (1) <br>

Comment: Have you tried updating `devtools`? If yes, is it installing now? If not, what version of `R` are you using?

Comment: Yes, it says no new update. Still having the problem to install. I am using R Studio version no Version 0.99.473. R version R version 2.15.3.