# RNeo4j Installation Hanging, not Completing

Tags: r, devtools, r-neo4j

I've tried installing `RNeo4j` package over and over, with no success - it keeps hanging, never finishing!

I tried installing the packages in RStudio (with `devtools::install_github("nicolewhite/RNeo4j")` ), and even the base R, just to be sure. I updated my `devtools` to the latest, and tried again. Same thing. It would just get to '`Installing other packages curl, httr, R6, stringi`' and hang there.

To confirm this wasn't an internet connection issue, I manually installed those listed packages (`httr`, `curl`, `R6`, `springi`) and tried running the `devtools` install again. Now, it says `Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘httr’`, even though I just installed it!

Is this a glitch from devtools? Or has the repo been moved? Kindly assist! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
library(devtools)

install_git("https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j")
```

Comment: Awesome! Successfully downloaded and loaded! Though for some reason, it reinstalled `httr` and `springi` (which I'd already just now installed, as I mentioned). Wonder why...do you perchance know? Thanks

Comment: glad that it worked!  Regarding re-installing dependencies- I am not sure, maybe it just updated to newer version...